# How to avoid askopenfilename from sending my toplevel window behind root

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is my code.

```
def UploadAction(event=None):

    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    if filename == '':
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Warning", "You did not select any file!", parent=GUI)
    else:
        print('Selected:', filename)
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Completed", "File Uploaded!", parent=GUI)
```

By setting (parent = root), my toplevel window, which is GUI, will come in front with the messagebox. But I want my GUI window to be in front of root but behind openfiledialog.

Comment: *But I want the GUI window to be always on top.* Are you looking for `GUI.attributes('-topmost', True)` ?

Comment: Thank you for answering. But your method will bring my GUI window even in front of openfile dialog. I do not want that. I want my GUI window to be in front of root but behind openfile dialog.

Comment: Should it be `parent=GUI` (I assume it is used in `askopenfilename()`) instead?

Comment: Please create a [mre] in order to get help, also take the time for a brief explaination of what you are trying to achive, what you have tried and how your code act differently from expected.

Comment: Thank you very much @acw1668. :) it worked. I was struggling with it since morning.